# Dart's equivalent for Java's StringBuilder

Tags: dart

Is there a Dart equivalent for Java's [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)?

I have looked into [StringBuffer](https://api.dartlang.org/1.14.2/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html), but that API doesn't have as many features as the StringBuilder. Methods like delete, reverse or variety for insert are missing in the StringBuffer.

Follow-up - [request feature](http://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25897)

Comment: It has `insert` but it named `write`

Answer (score 78):

Dart names them differently

`insert` becomes `write`
`delete` becomes `clear`

for `reverse` you can call `toString` and then `reverse`.

**Example:**

```
  final buffer = StringBuffer();
  
  buffer.write("Hello");
  buffer.write("world");
  
  print(buffer.toString());
  print(buffer.toString().split('').reversed.join());
```

Comment: Clear essentially deletes everything. What if you want to delete a single character or subset of characters within the string buffer?
Possibly like this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)

Comment: I guess you need to create a new `StringBuffer` and copy the part before the char and after the char. You can create an issue in http://github.com/dart-lang/sdk if you think other methods should be added.

Comment: Interesting. Ill create an issue for it. Thanks.

Comment: check the "Building from parts" in this tutorial http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/01/strings-in-dart.html

Comment: As a followup, I created the issue sometime back.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/25897

Comment: 'new' keyword isn't necessary.